# android GPS force close

Tags: android, gps

i m getting a force close on my HTC desire while i m trying to get location via GPS on google map. usually, what i have seen force closes occur due to problems in the manifest.xml file.following is part of my manifest file. is there any problem with it?

```
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION?

Comment: yes coarse location is for wifi and fine location is for gps i guess.however, i solved the problem by just rewriting the manifest file!!nothing special..however..thx abhinav